# Windows batch to read path from XML

Tags: xml, batch-file

I need to read a path from an attribute in an XML file but spaces are making me problems.

```
@echo off

:: Write a VBS file for getting modfolder from gameSettings.xml
> "%TEMP%\moddir.vbs" (
echo.Dim oXml: Set oXml = CreateObject^("Microsoft.XMLDOM"^)
echo.oXml.Load WScript.Arguments.Item^(0^)
echo.Dim oDoc: Set oDoc = oXml.documentElement
echo.
echo.For Each node In oDoc.childNodes
echo.   If ^(node.nodeName = "modsDirectoryOverride"^) And ^(node.getAttribute^("active"^) = "true"^) Then
echo.       WScript.Echo node.getAttribute^("directory"^)
echo.   End If
echo.Next
echo.Set oXml = Nothing
)

:: Setting Mod directory
SETLOCAL
for /f %%i in ('cscript %TEMP%\moddir.vbs "%UserDocs%\My Games\FarmingSimulator2017\gameSettings.xml" //Nologo') do set "moddir=%%i"

echo moddir = %moddir%
```

The line in the XML file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no" ?>
<gameSettings revision="11">
<modsDirectoryOverride active="true" directory="D:\games\Farming Simulator\Farming simulator 17\Mods"/>
</gameSettings>
```

The variable `moddir` is set to `D:\games\Farming` although it should be `D:\games\Farming Simulator\Farming simulator 17\Mods`.

Comment: By default the `for /f` has a space as delimter. To change that either user `For /f "tokens=*" ...` or `for /f "delims=" ...`

Comment: Lifesaver! thx @LotPings ! Exactly what i needed! Not sure if I and how I can mark a comment as accepted answer.

Comment: @gec100 remove `vbscript` tag from the question.

Comment: If you are going to use Vbscript to get the data you want from the XML file, then just code the whole script in Vbscript.

Comment: this is someone else's script that i'm adopting to my needs. i'm no expert in xml, vbs or batch. I can just understand code good enough to make few changes to it. Sometimes with some help from stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q41196420.txt"
FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1,3delims=<=>/" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 IF "%%~a"=="modsDirectoryOverride active" ECHO dir=%%~b
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q41196420.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Here's an easy way - simply select suitable tokens and delimiters and filter with an `if`

---

Best to provide the **problem** to be solved, not a solution-to-fix alone.

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q41196420.txt"
FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1-7delims=<=>/" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
ECHO + %%a + %%b + %%c + %%d + %%e + %%f + %%g +
REM note content of "%%x" - %%~x = %%x minus quotes at either end
REM we may need to tokenise "%%a" using spaces as delimiters
 FOR /f "tokens=1*delims= " %%m IN ("%%a") DO (
 REM %%a..%%g, %%m and %%n are in-context
  ECHO + %%m + %%n
  REM same formula for "%%b"
  FOR /f "tokens=1*delims= " %%p IN ("%%b") DO (
  REM %%a..%%g, %%m and %%n are in-context
   ECHO + %%p + %%q
   ECHO + %%a + %%b + %%c + %%d + %%e + %%f + %%g + %%m + %%n + %%p + %%q +
   REM So, select your parts. if /i=case-insensitive since I abhor CaMeLcAsE
   IF /i "%%~m"=="modsdirectoryoverride" IF /i "%%n"=="active" IF /i "%%~p"=="true" ECHO.&ECHO ***Directory=%%~c*** or ***Directory=%%c*** as you wish
  )
 )
 REM %%a..%%g are in-context, %%m and %%n are not
 ECHO.
)

GOTO :EOF
```

If you read the documentation (`for /? |more` from the prompt) then you'll likely be befuddled.

The code above displays how the line can be disassembled in batch, the important point being the conditional selection of the directoryname.

Take any line of text. This could be one of a series of lines in a file, a series of lines output from a command or even a variable.

First, you use `delims` to specify what delimiters to use. The line is seen as a series of tokens separated by a [sequence of] delimiter[s]

so `abc/123:ghij/:/hello` is seen as tokens `abc`, `123`, `ghij` and `hello` if `delims` is set to `/:`. By default, it is set to comma and space.

The `tokens` keyword assigns the selected strings to `metavariables` (the loop-control variables+). If the metavariable is `%%a` then the lowest selected token is assigned to `%%a`, the next lowest to `%%b` and so on. `*` is a special which means "everything after the highest token selected, including delimiters". `tokens` defaults to `1`.

So, applying `tokens=1,3` to the above tokenised `abc/123:ghij/:/hello` with metavariable `%%a` will set `%%a=abc` (1st) and `%%b=ghij` (3rd).

Beyond that, you may need `usebackq` to allow a filename in quotes (required if the full name includes spaces) to be read; if `usebackq` is omitted, a quoted string will be used literally.

Comment: ah, i've barely make my self understand how this vbs file works. I've never used tokens and delimiters before so i do not quite understand whats happening there.

Comment: If i change the active attribute to false, i'll still get the path. So instead of reading active word it should read the true or false value. I still like more vbs version cause it searches for specific attribute-value combination instead of counting words and spaces.

Comment: Thx for your answer @Magoo . This tokens/delims thingy is definitely something i'll have to look more in to it.

Answer (score 1):

I offer you a pure Batch file alernative solution that is simpler, but have the disadvantage that it only works with the xml file format you shown.

The `findstr` command can extract lines from a file that have a given string. For example, `findstr "modsDirectoryOverride" "gameSettings.xml"` command show this line:

```
<modsDirectoryOverride active="true" directory="D:\games\Farming Simulator\Farming simulator 17\Mods"/>
```

If we separate this line based on `for /F` command, that use the space as default separator, and include these options: `for /F "tokens=1,2*" %%a in ('previous line') do ...`, you'll realize that the `for` parameters have these values:

```
%%a have <modsDirectoryOverride
%%b have active="true"
%%c have directory="D:\games\Farming Simulator\Farming simulator 17\Mods"/>
```

Then, we can execute `set %%b` and `set %%c` commands, that would be equivalent to these commands:

```
set active="true"
set directory="D:\games\Farming Simulator\Farming simulator 17\Mods"/>
```

After that, you just need to test if `%active%` is `"true"` to show the directory, and that is it! **`;)`** The only detail is that the value of `%directory%` start with quote and ends with `"/>`, so these characters must be stripped from the output:

```
@echo off
setlocal

for /F "tokens=1,2*" %%a in ('findstr "modsDirectoryOverride" "gameSettings.xml"') do (
   set %%b
   set %%c
)
if %active% equ "true" echo %directory:~1,-3%
```

Comment: thx Aacini . That would definitely make code cleaner. But as i've said to Magoo i've never used tokens/delims before and i'm still trying to fit my head around it.

Comment: Precisely: my answer tries to be a clear example of how `"tokens=1,2*" %%a ...` works. The first (number `1`) space-separated _token_ (string of characters) is assigned to `%%a`; the next token (number `2`) is assigned to the next letter (`%%b`); the rest of tokens (indicated by the `*` after the `2`) are assigned to `%%c`...